# My Vue+Laravel App doesn't want to do Vue on Heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku

I have a Laravel+Vue app that I successfully installed on Heroku and Laravel part works here (https://shoomilka-todoapp.herokuapp.com/), but my Vue code for this application doesn't want to work. Code you can see here https://github.com/shoomilka/todoapp.

Can you help me, please to fix the error of why Vue doesn't work on Heroku?

It works on local environment well.

Answer (score 1):

Try inspect your website and look at the console tab. you will see this error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://shoomilka-todoapp.herokuapp.com/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://shoomilka-todoapp.herokuapp.com/js/app.js?time=1590194712'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default.

The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the content as HTTPS instead of HTTP. you can use laravel [secure_assets](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-secure-asset) method this generates a URL for an asset using HTTPS

```
<script src="{{ secure_assets('js/app.js') }}?time={{ time() }}"></script>
```

or simply just set `'url' => 'https://youDomain.com'` in `config/app.php` and `.env` `APP_URL=https://yourDomain.com`